# Dynamic groupby table in PowerBI

Tags: powerbi, dax, visualization, powerbi-desktop, slicers

My table has a following structure:

| Conference | People Attending | Company | Market Value ($) | Employees | Offices |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| TechCon 2023 | John Doe | ABC Corp | 10,000,000 | 500 | 10 |
| TechCon 2023 | Jane Smith | XYZ Inc | 8,500,000 | 350 | 8 |
| TechCon 2023 | John Doe | PQR Co | 6,200,000 | 250 | 5 |
| TechCon 2023 | Mark Lee | MNO Ltd | 4,500,000 | 200 | 4 |
| ExpoX 2023 | Emily Chen | RST Corp | 9,800,000 | 450 | 9 |
| ExpoX 2023 | Mark Lee | UVW Inc | 7,600,000 | 300 | 6 |
| ExpoX 2023 | Mike Smith | JKL Co | 5,400,000 | 180 | 3 |
| ExpoX 2023 | Emily Chen | GHI Ltd | 3,700,000 | 150 | 2 |
| SummitTech | Sarah Liu | DEF Corp | 11,500,000 | 600 | 12 |
| SummitTech | Chris Kim | HIJ Inc | 9,200,000 | 400 | 8 |
| SummitTech | John Doe | STU Co | 7,800,000 | 300 | 6 |
| SummitTech | Emily Chen | VWX Ltd | 4,900,000 | 200 | 4 |
| FutureTech | Mark Lee | LMN Corp | 13,200,000 | 700 | 14 |
| FutureTech | Emily Chen | OPQ Inc | 10,500,000 | 450 | 9 |
| FutureTech | John Doe | WXY Co | 8,100,000 | 350 | 7 |
| FutureTech | Jane Smith | ZAB Ltd | 5,600,000 | 250 | 5 |

I want to make a groupby on conferences my default view:

| Conference | People Attending | Total Market Value ($) | Total Employees | Total Offices |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| TechCon 2023 | John Doe, Jane Smith, Mark Lee | 29,200,000 | 1,050 | 22 |
| ExpoX 2023 | Mike Smith, Mark Lee, Emily Chen | 26,500,000 | 780 | 20 |
| SummitTech | John Doe, Sarah Liu, Chris Kim | 19,100,000 | 1,200 | 24 |
| FutureTech | John Doe, Jane Smith, Mark Lee, Emily Chen | 41,900,000 | 1,600 | 39 |

But to be able to pick a person creating a personalised view aggregating values for her/his companies only using a slicer of some sort:

| Conference | People Attending | Total Market Value ($) | Total Employees | Total Offices |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| TechCon 2023 | John Doe | 16,200,000 | 750 | 15 |
| ExpoX 2023 | John Doe | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| SummitTech | John Doe | 7,800,000 | 300 | 6 |
| FutureTech | John Doe | 8,100,000 | 350 | 7 |

How do I do that?